# Jest mockImplementation confusion

Tags: node.js, mocking, jestjs

I must not be understanding something correctly.
As per reading the docs and the few examples I've seen online. I'm doing this:

```
// utils/handleError.js
export default () => {
  return {
    status: 'error'
  }
}
```

```
// utils/index.js
export { default as handleError } from './handleError'
...
```

```
// auth.js
import { handleError } from './utils'
export default async (key) => {
  if (!key) {
    return handleError()
  }
  ...
  // more async stuff here
}
```

```
// auth.test.js
import auth from './auth'
import { handleError } from './utils'

// also tried importing it directly
// import handleError from './utils/handleError'

jest.mock('./utils')

describe('Auth', () => {
  it('should error when no key present', async () => {
    handleError.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ status: 'check'})
    const res = await auth(false)
    expect(auth.status).toBe('check')
  })
})
```

I'm getting that `_.handleError.default.mockImplementation` is not a function.
My goal is to ultimately change the return value of handleError per test. (I know this is a bad example and handleError would probably never change. I'm just using it as an example here)

When I explicitly mock each fn

```
jest.mock('./utils', () => ({
  handleError: () => ({ status: 'poop' })
}))
```

like so, it works as expected however changing the return per test becomes messy with a chain of `mockImplementationOnce()` or the like.

What am i misunderstanding here? How should I properly mock the `handleError` and its return when I test `auth`?

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 0):

Mock the return value of `handleError` per test is correct.

You can use syntactic sugar function [mockFn.mockResolvedValueOnce(value)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue) instead of using `mockImplementationOnce` for mocking quickly.